# Tricky grep with quotes & brackets in input (json response)

Tags: json, bash, curl

I m trying to extract out the numeric (timestamp) pattern from json response in bash script:

Here is the code snippet >

```
 response=$(curl -isb -H "Accept: application/json" http://host:5000/app?q=1)
 #response=$(wget -q -O - http://host:5000/app?q=1)
 echo "Response : $response"
 latest=$(echo $response | grep -oP "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,}")
 echo "Latest version is : $latest"
```

However when I run the test the output of grep in empty

```
Response : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: rack.session=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiRTMyYWM2NGJjNzBhMDczYWQ5ZDcz%0AMDQ4MjA2ZjYwMzY4NDMxMzhmYTEwY2Q2MDEwMmU5NjA0YmY4MDBmNmRhZDQG%0AOwBGSSIJY3NyZgY7AEZJIiU4OTAyMDk4MDcxOTM5MWY1MmMzMzZlZjhiNjNi%%%0ABjsARkkiGUhUVFBfQUNDRVBUX0xBTkdVQUdFBjsAVEkiLWRhMzlhM2VlNWU2%0AYjRiMGQzMjU1YmZlZjk1NjAxODkwYWZkODA3MDkGOwBG%0A--3d18f21cd9851f99ff05b45556a78988132221c9; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Length: 40

["env-svr-app-mod-2014-05-15-155"]
Latest version is :
```

So the curl output has timestamp in it.
I m expecting to see 2014-05-15-155 in the output.

I have tried couple of different option (and wget) but looks like I m missing something obvious here.

Is it the qupts/ brackets/ new line in the curl output itself that's causing issue?
(I remember seeing this work couple of times)

Appreciate nudges! Thx.

Comment: Works fine for me as is.  You have this tagged bash but not linux.  Are you on OSX?

Comment: Try quoting $response on the line with grep. bash tends to convert newlines into spaces. It should not matter in your case, but... For what it's worth, your script works fine for me on ubuntu 12.10 and FreeBSD-9 in both cases in bash. zsh, on the other hand was acting rather weirdly -- while it did echo/grep/assign value correctly, it also echoed $response on the console, though it was not via stdout or stderr.

Comment: The HTTP header says "Content-Length: 40" but the response has only 34 visible characters (and possibly a CRLF included in the count, which would make it 36). Perhaps you should take a look at the response with `hd` to see what's not visible.

Comment: @ArtemB Perfect! I added quoted $response and now script works as expected! Can you post this as an answer so that i can accept it -)

Comment: @Rishi Just did. Those pesky newlines and other whitespaces...

Comment: @John1024 thx for your inputs, I m on centOS 5. Works fine after adding the quotes to $response.

Comment: @rici interesting point but I m not sure if that's something I should worry about for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try quoting `$response` on the line with grep. bash tends to convert newlines into spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you grep command by:

```
perl -lne '/\w+-(\d+-.*)"/ && print $1'
```

Ex:

```
[root@TIAGO-TEST tmp]# cat response 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: rack.session=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiRTMyYWM2NGJjNzBhMDczYWQ5ZDcz%0AMDQ4MjA2ZjYwMzY4NDMxMzhmYTEwY2Q2MDEwMmU5NjA0YmY4MDBmNmRhZDQG%0AOwBGSSIJY3NyZgY7AEZJIiU4OTAyMDk4MDcxOTM5MWY1MmMzMzZlZjhiNjNi%%%0ABjsARkkiGUhUVFBfQUNDRVBUX0xBTkdVQUdFBjsAVEkiLWRhMzlhM2VlNWU2%0AYjRiMGQzMjU1YmZlZjk1NjAxODkwYWZkODA3MDkGOwBG%0A--3d18f21cd9851f99ff05b45556a78988132221c9; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Length: 40

["env-svr-app-mod-2014-05-15-155"]
[root@TIAGO-TEST tmp]# cat response| perl -lne '/\w+-(\d+-.*)"/ && print $1'
2014-05-15-155
```

Comment: thx, however I want to implement this using curl/wget command (w/o any calls to perl).